# UWP: Upload large files to OneDrive using OneDrive SDK

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

I can upload "small" files (< 100 MB) using the following code:

```
await OneDriveClient
      .Drive
      .Special
      .AppRoot
      .Children["filename"]
      .Content
      .Request()
      .PutAsync<Item>(contentStream);
```

For Large files (> 100 MB) I read that you have to create an `Upload Session`.
Something like this?

```
UploadSession uSession = await OneDriveClient
                               .Drive
                               .Special
                               .AppRoot
                               .Children["filename"]
                               .CreateSession(VarChunkedUploadSessionDescriptor)
                               .Request()
                               .PostAsync();
```

I am not sure what steps are after this? (Or even this is the right step!). Would appreciate some spoon-feeding :) Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I found a similar four month old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408692/cannot-upload-to-onedrive-using-the-new-sdk Hope this issue is taken care of in the latest version but I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The sdk is a bit confusing on this. Note, the ItemWithPath is without the drive root....

```
//uploadPath = "/documentname.docx";
//filename = "documentname.docx";

var request = service.OneDriveClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(uploadPath).CreateSession(new ChunkedUploadSessionDescriptor() { Name = Uri.EscapeUriString(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)) }).Request();
var session = request.PostAsync().Result;


using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Helpers.ChunkedUploadProvider chunk = new Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Helpers.ChunkedUploadProvider(
            session, client, stream);
                var item = chunk.UploadAsync().Result; 
            }
        }
```